# Tomcat9, in local it adds the body. In server does not

Tags: response, tomcat9

I'm moving my development to one tomcat in docker.

I have two environments in RestClient, one using the tomcat in local and the other for the Dockered.

The first issue I had was resolved, it was the one for invalid characters in the request.

Now the issue is in the response. From the request, I receive the code 200, using the local tomcat I receive the body but using the Dockered, I did not. It happens in some requests but I have other endpoints sending the body with no issue.

Did somebody found something similar? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Regards,

Comment: Can you please show more information? E.g. the requests and exact information about the requests and responses?

Comment: of course: The request is in this way: https://${"url"}${port}/LabPLANET-API/frontEnd/sampleAPIfrontEnd?schemaPrefix=process-us&actionName=GET_SAMPLETEMPLATES&finalToken=eyJ1c2VyREIiOiJsYWJwbGFuZXQiLCJlU2lnbiI6Im1hbGEiLCJ1c2VyREJQYXNzd29yZCI6Imxhc2xlY2h1Z2FzIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiYXBwU2Vzc2lvbklkIjoiMTIiLCJ1c2VyUm9sZSI6ImNvb3JkaW5hdG9yIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYiLCJpbnRlcm5hbFVzZXJJRCI6IjEifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJMYWJQTEFORVRkZXN0cmFuZ2lz

Comment: The Response code is 200

Comment: This is the code for the response:                     Response.ok().build();
                    response.getWriter().write(myData);          . myData is a String variable. gson class is part of the project, it works fine in local in both Tomcat and Glassfish

Comment: and this is a pure servlet, no spring in use

Comment: Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: xxxx
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS: False
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL: True
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: xxx
Referer: http://x:y/es6prod/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100

Comment: Have you tested if your servlet is actually executed?